# New-AzPolicyDefinition Creation of Azure policy definition through PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, azure-policy

I am trying to create a Azure policy definition but getting error. This JSON code is taken from a built-in script from Azure policy "IP Forwarding on your virtual machine should be disabled"
Below is my script

```
$Policy=
'{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Disable-IP-Forwarding",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "Disable-IP-Forwarding-Test.",
    "metadata": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "category": "Security Center"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "AuditIfNotExists",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "AuditIfNotExists"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "in": [
          "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
          "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Security/complianceResults",
          "name": "disableIPForwarding",
          "existenceCondition": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Security/complianceResults/resourceStatus",
            "in": [
              "Monitored",
              "OffByPolicy",
              "Healthy"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/Disable-IP-Forwarding",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "Disable-IP-Forwarding"
}'

$definition = New-AzPolicyDefinition    -Name "Disable-IP-Forwarding"  -Description "Disable-IP-Forwarding-Test." -Policy $Policy
```

Below are the pictures from Powershell showing error.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttj4w.png) & [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0JCv.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttj4w.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0JCv.png

I also tried with removing single quotes in policy rule as in [here(click Here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWIqD.png)

**Error: After removing Single quote **

New-AzPolicyDefinition : InvalidPolicyRule : Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'properties' on object of type 'PolicyRuleDefinition'. Path 'properties'.'.
CorrelationId: 7e754d56-2e8e-4323-8650-ae620bb60573
At line:70 char:15

- ... efinition = New-AzPolicyDefinition    -Name "Disable-IP-Forwarding"   ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzPolicyDefinition], ErrorResponseMessageException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzurePolicyDefinitionCmdlet

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out as per in below link, used a Here-String for the JSON body:
[link] (powershell.org/2019/04/hear-hear-for-here-strings)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicydefinition?view=azps-4.4.0), When you create the Policy definition using `New-AzPolicyDefinition` PowerShell Command . Your policy definition should be in the below format:

```
{
    "parameters": {
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "AuditIfNotExists",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "AuditIfNotExists"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "in": [
          "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
          "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Security/complianceResults",
          "name": "disableIPForwarding",
          "existenceCondition": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Security/complianceResults/resourceStatus",
            "in": [
              "Monitored",
              "OffByPolicy",
              "Healthy"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

You can pass the description, mode, metadata, display name as the parameters in the command.

Another problem, removing the single quotes and passing `"[parameters(effect)]"`, this will give you another error. So the best way to pass the policy definition is saving it in the json file and pass the path to the command.

```
$definition = New-AzPolicyDefinition    -Name "Disable-IP-Forwarding"  -Description "Disable-IP-Forwarding-Test." -Policy "D:\Learning\policy1.json"
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. 
However, I am working on some automation where I will not have a place to store the file, so will have to deal with everything on same page. Could you please suggest any way if it can be done on PowerShell editor itself.

Comment: I figured it out as per in below link, used a Here-String for the JSON body:
[link] (https://powershell.org/2019/04/hear-hear-for-here-strings/)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it was useful. As the error was related to template which you posted.